# Setting the table name dynamically in Slick 3.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I have two tables that are identical, each in a different database. Also, the tables have different names.

I have hardcoded the name of the table in the class `BankDB`:

```
class BankDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bank](tag, "banks1") {

  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
 // other columns
```

What I need is, depending on the database name, to set the name of the table, like so:

```
 val tableName = if (dbName == "DB1") "banks1" else "banks2"
```

And then use tableName in TableQuery to have Slick point to the correct table:

```
    val db = Database.forConfig(dbName)
    try {
      val banks = TableQuery[BankDB](tableName)  // <== this doesn't work
      val future = db.run(banks.filter(_.sk === sk).result)
      val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
      result
    } finally db.close
```

Is this possible? or I need to define to classes, one for each database?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-slick-multidb). Also, for table names, you could parametrize [DAO](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-slick-multidb/blob/master/src/main/scala/basic/DAO.scala#L6) class with `tableName: String` for example...

Answer (score 0):

```
class BankDB(tag: Tag,tableName: String) extends Table[Bank](tag, tableName) 
def getTableQuery(tableName: String) = 
   TableQuery[BankDB]((t: slick.lifted.Tag) => new BankDB(t, tableName))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.